# Get std::list by reference

Tags: c++

I have a `Poly3D` class in C++, which has a sole member: `list<Point_3>`

```
using namespace std;

struct Poly3D
{
public:
    Poly3D(const list<Point_3> &ptList);


private:
    list<Point_3> ptList;

};
```

My question is, how to GET ( in the sense of C#) by reference, so that the same copy with be returned every time I access the `Poly3D.ptList`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <list>
using namespace std;

struct Point_3{
};

struct Poly3D
{
public:
    Poly3D(const list<Point_3> &ptList);
    list<Point_3>& GetPointList();


private:
    list<Point_3> ptList;

};

list<Point_3>& Poly3D::GetPointList(){
    return ptList;
}

int main(void){
    list<Point_3> myList;
    Poly3D myPoly(myList);
    list<Point_3>& myListRef = myPoly.GetPointList();
}
```

Comment: I think the `const` method for `GetPointList()` is not working-- it can't even compile.

Comment: Forget that `const`, it's a habit of mine to always declare getter functions const.. :') Edited, should compile now.

Comment: According to [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984107/returning-stl-lists-as-argument#comment46271122_984133), compiling `list<Point_3>& GetPointList()` succeeds depending on the compiler. Add a `typedef list<Point_3>& MyListRef` and return that type to get it to compile.

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to provide direct access to the `list`, then just write a getter that returns by reference:

```
struct Poly3D
{
public:
    ...

    list<Point_3> &getList()
    {
        return ptList;
    }

...
};
```

But if you're doing that, you may as well just make the `list` member `public`!

Comment: Dammit, you beat me to it. :)