# Is it possible to store the memory location from an iterator into a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a vector of teams, which each hold players.  I need to get all the players into one vector so I can sort them and display them.  I only need to know how to take the `vectorOfTeams[i].getVectorOfPlayers()[j]` and turn it into a memory location of the player to store into a new array.  Unfortunately this is for an assignment at my school and I'm not allowed to post the code anywhere at all.  Hopefully I'm making sense.

Comment: How about `&vectorOfTeams[i].getVectorOfPlayers()[j]`?

Comment: After the loop exits the memory locations given turn into garbage. :((

Comment: check if `getVectorOfPlayers()` returns *by value* and change it to *by const reference*. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456778/function-in-c-returns-by-value-or-by-reference).

Comment: `const vector<Player> getPlayersVec() const {return this->const&players;}`  is giving me an unqualified-id error.  I'm new to pointers so I'm sorry if missing something obvious.

Comment: expected unqualified-id error**

Comment: Don't store pointers to `vector` members, as they travel in memory when the vector does a reallocation. Instead you can a) store the pointer to `vector` itself + an index into it, b) store objects in  somethnig like `list` instead, c) store your objects on the heap yourself instead (like `vector<unique_ptr<Player>>`).

Answer (score 0):

You could construct a vector of pointers to players, `std::vector<Player*>`, fill it with pointers to all the players of all teams, using `&vectorOfTeams[i].getVectorOfPlayers()[j]`, as noted by Vaughn Cat, and sort this vector of pointers to players using [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with a custom comparator.

Since you will be dealing with pointers here, be sure all the actual *Player objects* still live, that is, make sure they are not a local variable and are instead created dynamically for instance.

Answer (score 0):

In most straight-forward thinking, `&(somePlayerVector[i])` should give you a "valid" address.

You may find it works for most case, BUT this is not a desirable way to keep the pointer.

That `Player` is only guaranteed to exist at the time of access.  There are lots of thing that can go wrong: vector can reallocate and then the memory location is no longer valid.

The safer way is to keep another `Player` object in your target array which is a copy of the `Player` in the original vector, so that you will no longer access the internal data of the vector after the line of getting the `Player`