# Operator Overload Confusion with custom Class

Tags: c++

I am following this tutorial on operator overloading: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-overloading-c/

Code snippet:

```
class Complex {
private:
    int real, imag;
public:
    Complex(int r = 0, int i = 0) { real = r;   imag = i; }

    // This is automatically called when '+' is used with 
    // between two Complex objects 
    Complex operator + (Complex const& obj) {
        Complex res;
        res.real = real + obj.real;
        res.imag = imag + obj.imag;
        return res;
    }
    void print() { cout << real << " + i" << imag << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Complex c1(10, 5), c2(2, 4);
    Complex c3 = c1 + c2;
    c3.print();
}
```

My question is, how does c++ know what to pass in to &obj and how does it know what to give to real and imag within the operator function? Like how does it know 10 for c1 goes to real and 2 for c2 goes to obj.real? It was never specified which object gets assigned to obj. Hell how does it even know to parse c1's values to real and imag within the operator function?

Comment: You do know that every member function in C++ gets passed a "hidden" argument, the "`this`" pointer, that refers to the current instance. Right?

Comment: `c1 + c2` translates into `c1.operator+(c2)` by definition.

Comment: The operand on the left hand side of operator+ will be bound to the implicit this operator as said above since operator+ is defined as a member function.

Comment: I see thanks... So if you call that + function, it ignores the c3 which I actually assumed was what we were working with, and looks at the left and right hand side of the operation to know what to assign to each side? I am surprised because c3 technically is what I am working with, Secondly, why do I need to return res? res is only a local variable, wouldn't it's data get destroyed once + is done, instead of it passing the summation data to real and img?

Comment: `c3` is not accessible inside `operator+`. The way to set its value is to return something from `operator+`. Assignment operator's (`=`) job is to assign the result returned by `operator+` to `c3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c1` is the object you're working with. That probably sounds confusing, so let me explain.

When you do this:

```
c1 + c2;
```

ignoring the return value for a second, that code is the same as doing this:

```
c1.operator+(c2);
```

So, `c1` is the base object on which the operator is called. In the same way that `c1.print()` uses `c1`'s values, calling the operator uses `c1`'s values by default, so to speak.

Why is `c1` called here and not `c2`? Like why isn't it the same as:

```
c2.operator+(c1);
```

This is because `c1` is on the left hand side. If `c2` were on the left hand side, like in the example `c2+c1`, then `operator+()` would get called on `c2` instead.

---

So, in short (and other words), C++ uses `operator+()`(and similar operators) by calling `operator+()` in the following format:

```
left.operator+(right);
```

This allows you to use `real` and `imag` like you would in `print()` for the left side's member variables, and `other.real` and `other.imag` for the right side's variables.

---

So, in the comments you asked a couple more questions that I figure might take more than a comment or two to answer, but are worth answering. So, here goes.

> So if you call that `+` function, it ignores the `c3` which I actually assumed was what we were working with, and looks at the left and right hand side of the operation to know what to assign to each side?

Correct. As far as **inside the function**, `operator+()` only looks at the objects immediately beside it (in this case, `c1` and `c2`) to perform the calculation.

> I am surprised because `c3` technically is what I am working with,

Ah, okay. Not for the calculation itself. Let's look at your `operator+()` closely again:

```
Complex operator + (Complex const& obj) {
    Complex res;
    res.real = real + obj.real;
    res.imag = imag + obj.imag;
    return res;
}
```

Here, you have a current object (which is where `real` and `imag` come from) and another object (which is where `obj.real` and `obj.imag` come from). It's these that make up `c1` and `c2`. These are the numbers you are actually adding.

`c3`, on the other hand, is the result of this addition. If I have something like this:

```
4 + 3 = 7
```

The operation `4+3` will have a result: `7`. That's what `c3` is here. Well, technically, that's what `res` is here. By returning `res`, you're returning the result. And in the case of `c3`, it's setting it's value to the returned result of `operator+()` via the assignment (`=`) operator.

> Secondly, why do I need to return `res`?

Already sort of covered that, but to be clear: `res` is the result of the operation. C++ wouldn't know how to get the result otherwise.

> `res` is only a local variable, wouldn't it's data get destroyed once `+` is done, instead of it passing the summation data to `real` and `imag`?

You seem to be confusing [returning by reference and returning by value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7456816/10957435). If you return a local variable by reference, absolutely. This will get destroyed. However, if you return by value, the result gets copied out almost by definition, so you're totally fine here in this example.

Comment: I see thanks... So if you call that + function, it ignores the c3 which I actually assumed was what we were working with, and looks at the left and right hand side of the operation to know what to assign to each side? I am surprised because c3 technically is what I am working with, Secondly, why do I need to return res? res is only a local variable, wouldn't it's data get destroyed once + is done, instead of it passing the summation data to real and img?

Comment: @edo101, the value `res` returned by `c1+c2` is assigned to `c3`. This behaviour is consistent with any other function. For example, `Complex c3 = c1.get_some_value();`, where the member function `get_some_value()` is `Complex get_some_value() { return /* some value */; }`. There is no magic in `operator+` once you understand how `+` translates into it.

Comment: @edo101 tried to address your questions in an edit. Please see my update.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Okay back to return by value... I thought things get destroyed once function call is done. In this case regardless of if by value or refrence, the value would get destroyed after function is done no? Or is this just how things are. Where if you return by value, the amount gets copied to be sent to whoever is calling the value. If this is the case, I'd think it'd work the same way for reference and pointer as well

Comment: @edo101, if return values had been destroyed before they had a chance to be assigned to anything, return values would have been totally useless.

Comment: @Evg thanks. quick question, is there a difference between (const Box& box2) and (Box const& box2) if you have a custom class called Box? And if so, what is the difference?

Comment: @edo101 No difference at all. Where you put `const` is just a matter of taste - termed "east const" and "west const".