# Can compilers optimize a single-argument pass-by-value function over its pass-by-const-reference counterpart?

Tags: c++

Aliasing is the main optimization issue with pass-by-const-reference functions that take multiple arguments; this has been pointed out in answers to similar questoins. However, [this particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2582942/3451226) also seems to suggest that the compiler can make more assumptions about a *single-argument* pass-by-value function than an otherwise identical pass-by-const-reference function.

This would imply that pass-by-value is the preferred strategy for small objects. While this seems like perfectly sound logic for an argument of a non-class type or a type with a `constexpr` copy constructor, I fail to see how these assumptions could be extended to an argument that does not meet these requirements. Take the following example:

##### foo.h

```cpp
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

struct Foo {
    int i;
    Foo(int i);
    Foo(const Foo &other);
    ~Foo();
};

void incrementNewestFoo();

#endif
```

##### foo.cpp

```cpp
#include "foo.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<Foo *> foos;

Foo::Foo(int i) : i(i) {
    foos.push_back(this);
}

Foo::Foo(const Foo &other) : i(other.i) {
    foos.push_back(this);
}
Foo::~Foo() {
    foos.erase(std::find(foos.cbegin(), foos.cend(), this));
}

void incrementNewestFoo() {
    foos.back()->i += 1;
}
```

##### main.cpp

```cpp
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void passByValue(Foo foo) {
    cout << foo.i << endl;
    incrementNewestFoo();
    cout << foo.i << endl;
}

void passByConstReference(const Foo &foo) {
    cout << foo.i << endl;
    incrementNewestFoo();
    cout << foo.i << endl;
}

int main() {
    Foo foo(0);
    passByValue(foo);
    passByConstReference(foo);
}
```

As far as I'm aware, the behavior of `main()` is well-defined according to the C++ standard. According to the previously linked answer, the most valuable assumption to be made about the pass-by-value function is that the value of `i` will not change between reads in most cases. However, it appears to me as though this assumption is invalid for any call to a function whose definition resides in another compilation unit (except for `const` member functions for which the pass-by-const-reference function can make the same assumption anyway). Perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: The compiler cannot assume `incrementNewestFoo()` will leave `foo.i` unchanged in either function.   In `passByConstReference()` all the `const` does is cause the compiler to diagnose attempts in the function to *change* non-mutable` state of `foo` or obtain a non-`const` reference or pointer to `foo`.    The compiler cannot routinely assume that the caller has not stored a non-`const` reference/pointer to the object it passes somewhere else, nor can it assume that `incrementNewestFoo()` doesn't modify that object by some other means - which, coincidentally, is exactly what your code does.

Comment: @Peter sorry if I wasn't clear, but that's exactly what I'm trying to point out with my example. To rephrase my question: is there anything that can be assumed about a pass-bt-value function that can't be assumed about a pass-by-const-reference function? [I see the suggestion that pass-by-value is often faster everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7456816/3451226), but I don't see how that could be possible.